# Why does OnTime not execute when a userform is open?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use a self-activating OnTime sub to edit some text in a UF control. However, I find that an `Application.OnTime` event won't start working *until*  the UserForm is closed.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172889/application-ontime-doesnt-work-with-userform) SO thread, I have placed the self-activating sub in a public sub in a regular module. However, this is to no avail.

**UF sub**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize
    TEST.loadingdots
End Sub
```

**Regular sub**

```
Public Sub loadingdots
    Debug.Print 4
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "loadingdots"
End Sub
```

The first "4" gets printed, then nothing. When I close the UF, the procedure gets executed as expected.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Not quite sure why it doesn't work for you, just using your code seems to work fine for me (i.e.: with the userform open, is keep printing "4" every 2 seconds).

Comment: @DarXyde that's very odd... That's the exact code I am using and it absolutely does not work for me.

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce your issue too. It's working fine. • But note that once `loadingdots` is started it will never stop again. You should use some global variable as stop criteria like `If Not stopit Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "loadingdots"` so you can set the global `stopit` to `True`. Otherwise this is endless.

Comment: @DarXyde got it figured out. Made a new, blank UF. Turns out the RefEdit control on the first UF prevented the subroutine from executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question for future reference**

When a UF holds a RefEdit control, an OnTime event won't be executed.

I created a new, blank UF, which caused no issues whatsoever.

Seems like RefEdits need to be approached with caution, similarly to how using a RefEdit control in a modeless userform [forces the user to close the Excel application through task manager](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/modeless.htm).