# Update userforms listboxes at every time inteval

Tags: excel, vba

I got around 30 listboxes in userform, which i want to update data from only worksheet1 as "Data" in every 10 sec. I am attaching my codes below which has tried. I am getting an error massage " Macro may not be available in the workbook or all macros may be disable". My sub procedure is on the same userform. And the error I am getting with this line "Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "UpdateListBoxes".

Any help will be greatly appriciated.
Many Thanks
Francisco[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32172889/application-ontime-doesnt-work-with-userform

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, I tried what you have suggested, the error is gone. but to see if it is updating every 5 seconds, I am not able to open the same workbook simultaneously on other computer on network. It opens in read only mode. I am not able to change the data on the worksheet. My intent was to have  it on network, multi user can access it. Is there any way out?.

Comment: You might consider writing the data to an external file and having the workbook update from that file.  I'm not clear what your use case is though, so some other approach might be more appropriate.  Where is the data coming from, and why monitor it in a userform and not a worksheet?

Comment: I have a excel worksheet 1 named as 'Data' . there are 6 userforms in this workbook which enters data and moves the data from columns to columns according to the stage through 6 userforms. It is like an application. These userform and data is in the same workbook. Each userform will be accessed by number of people at the same time on a network. That's how it should be. But I think, I have to separate the data and userform to get it work, as you said. But don't know how.